# How to delete all models in mongodb & Signup a user before starting the test?

Tags: mongodb, express, jestjs

I create a REST API service using MongoDB & Express in NodeJS. The service is about signup, login, CRUD operation to-dos. I wrote an integration test for the login and signup operations. The signup works perfectly on the first test but after the first test it's not signing up because the user has been already on the db. So in BeforeEach I deleted all the users and signup a user before the test starts. In the test, signup works perfect but sign in using the registered user in before each is not working. I hope u got my question. Here I am sharing the code

```
    const request = require('supertest')
    const app = require('../../server')
    const User = require('../../models/User')

    const userOne = {

        name:"XXX",
        email:"YYY@yahoo.com",
        password:"123456"

    }


    beforeEach(async(done)=>{
        await User.deleteMany()
        await new User(userOne).save()
        done()
    })

    test("Should signup a user",async()=>{
        await request(app).post('/api/users').send({
                name:"RRR",
                email:"KKK@yahoo.com",
                password:"123456"

        }).expect(200)
    })

   test("Should Signin a user",async()=>{
       await request(app).post('/api/auth').send({

            email:userOne.email,
            password:userOne.password

      }).expect(200)
  })
```

The error is like this:

● Should Signin a user

```
expected 200 "OK", got 400 "Bad Request"
```

Comment: can you add some delay between signup and sign in? and also in between check the collection for the user doc you have just signed up for after signup and before sign in..

Comment: What is the implemented code handling the POST? You should probably also add some logging in that method to see how exactly you are getting to the 400 error. Just as a note doing a `deleteMany()` and inserting one user `beforeEach` is probably overkill, and you likely only need *clean* and produce expected data only **once** before running ALL tests, rather than *each*. Seems more likely there is a problem in the POST handler implementation anyway. i.e "not hashing a password" or similar missed logic.

Comment: you have any backend validation for request data that you are sending

Answer (score 0):

Your signup test is failing because you creating the user in the database before each test. Assuming the code is making the request is working well, then it's failing because the user exists in the database already.

You should consider wrapping your tests within `describe` blocks that encapsulates related test together. In this way you could have a set of tests for the signup and the tests for the login afterward when you get sure the user exists in the database already. You can use `beforeAll` for that purpose.

```
const request = require('supertest')
const app = require('../../server')
const User = require('../../models/User')

const userOne = {
    name: "XXX",
    email: "YYY@yahoo.com",
    password: "123456"
}

describe('Auth Integration Tests', () => {
    describe('Signup', () => {
        it('should return a succesful response', () => {
            await request(app).post('/api/users').send({
                name: "RRR",
                email: "KKK@yahoo.com",
                password: "123456"
            }).expect(200)
        })
    });

    describe('Signin', () => {
        beforeAll(async () => {
            await User.deleteMany()
            await new User(userOne).save()
            done()
        });

        it('should return a succesful response', () => {
            await request(app).post('/api/auth').send({
                email: userOne.email,
                password: userOne.password
            }).expect(200)
        })
    })
});
```